# Edit only those lines that follow a pattern in a text file?

Tags: bash, text, awk, grep

I have a text file of the form:

**Example input file**

```
atomic structure.
created 8/4/15. author: becko
molecule name here
 O    0.000000 0    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       0    0    0
 C    1.422713 1    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       1    0    0
 C    1.536633 1  109.666084 1    0.000000 0       2    1    0
 C    1.523232 1  110.673515 1   53.747574 1       3    2    1
 C    1.524902 1  110.675377 1  -51.051605 1       4    3    2
 C    1.524624 1  110.815956 1   53.399712 1       5    4    3
 O    1.388625 1  108.653427 1  -68.335587 1       2    3    4
 O    1.418326 1  111.098351 1   58.126965 1       3    2    7
 O    1.429752 1  106.981445 1 -172.599930 1       4    3    2
 O    1.431727 1  110.929413 1  171.804962 1       5    4    3
 C    1.389881 1  117.191086 1   95.674500 0      10    5    4
 C    1.529863 1  107.679131 1  146.326675 0      11   10    5
 C    1.524202 1  110.428741 1  170.992218 1      12   11   10
```

The format is: Three initial header lines, which contain title, author and so on, followed by a table, with 10 columns and any number of rows. The first column is textual (usually a single character), columns 2, 4 and 6 contain decimal numbers, and the remaining columns are non-negative integers.

I need a command to find all the lines that contain, for example, a `3` in the 8th column and a `2` in the 9th column. The command should return a list of the line numbers following this pattern. How can I do this in a bash script? I want to assign the list of line numbers to a variable (like `lines=7 11`), so that I can loop through its contents later in the script.

**Edit:** Following the suggestion by @shelter, I'll post my full problem. 
I need to find all the lines that contain, for example, a `3` in the 8th column and a `2` in the 9th column. Then I need to add/subtract a fixed number, say `3.4`, to the 6th column of all these lines. How can I do this?

Given the previous example input file, I expect to get the following output file:

**Example output**

```
atomic structure.
created 8/4/15. author: becko
molecule name here
 O    0.000000 0    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       0    0    0
 C    1.422713 1    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       1    0    0
 C    1.536633 1  109.666084 1    0.000000 0       2    1    0
 C    1.523232 1  110.673515 1   57.147574 1       3    2    1
 C    1.524902 1  110.675377 1  -51.051605 1       4    3    2
 C    1.524624 1  110.815956 1   53.399712 1       5    4    3
 O    1.388625 1  108.653427 1  -68.335587 1       2    3    4
 O    1.418326 1  111.098351 1   61.526965 1       3    2    7
 O    1.429752 1  106.981445 1 -172.599930 1       4    3    2
 O    1.431727 1  110.929413 1  171.804962 1       5    4    3
 C    1.389881 1  117.191086 1   95.674500 0      10    5    4
 C    1.529863 1  107.679131 1  146.326675 0      11   10    5
 C    1.524202 1  110.428741 1  170.992218 1      12   11   10
```

Comment: `awk '{if($8 == 3 || $9==2) {print NF}' file` answers your immediate question. You'll almost certainly do better by doing all your processing in one awk process, rather than rely a list of line numbers. Edit your question to include your required output from the above sample data, with a description of any logic rules, and you'll get a much better piece of code to work with. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks. I edited the question to include my full purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Simple awk script:

```
awk '$8==3 && $9==2{print NR}'
```

That will produce one number per line, but you can still assign to a variable:

```
lines=$(awk '$8==3 && $9==2{print NR}' file.tsv)
```

or, with bash, as an array:

```
lines=($(awk '$8==3 && $9==2{print NR}' file.tsv))
```

If you really wanted all the numbers to be on a single line:

```
awk '$8==3 && $9==2{printf "%d ",NR}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `col8`, `col9` and `add` are bash variables holding the values that you want to match in column 8 and 9 and the value you want to add to column 6, respectively, (eg `col8=3 col9=2 add=3.4`) try:

```
awk '$8==a && $9==b{$6+=c}1' a=$col8 b=$col9 c=$add input-file
```

Note that this will slightly modify the spacing of the ouput.  The simplest way to make the output uniform (but still different than the original) is probably:

```
awk '$8==a && $9==b{$6+=c}{$1=$1}1' a=$col8 b=$col9 c=$add input-file
```

More important that the spacing issue (which you can solve with printf) is the precision of the data, so you'll probably want:

```
awk '$8==a && $9==b{$6+=c}1' CONVFMT=%0.9g  a=$col8 b=$col9 c=$add input-file
```

This simply assigns the shell variables col8, col9, and add to the awk variables a, b, and c and then iterates through the lines of the file.  When the columns match (the rule `$8==a && $9==b` evaluates to true), the arithmetic is performed.  The `1` causes each line to be printed.

Comment: Can you give a rough idea of how this command works? In particular, what is the meaning of the `k` in `k$9`, and why are you assigning variables `a,b,c` *after* the `awk` action declaration? Thanks

Comment: Added an explanation.  The `k` was a typo, which awk was evaluation as the empty string and concatenating with the value in column 9.  Not sure how that slipped through quality control!

Comment: The assignments occur after the awk command because that's how awk works.  The usage is `awk program [file]` where any filename that contains a `=` is treated as a variable assignment.  Often, people will use `-v` to make assignments, or put them in a BEGIN block, but I find this usage simplest.  It is (almost) strictly a stylistic choice.  The biggest advantage I find with this technique is that you can easily modify variables between input files.

Comment: It's not a stylistic choice - variables inited with `-v` are populated in the BEGIN section while those set after the script aren't, escapes are handled completely differently in the 2 approaches, the vars will appear in the ARGV array if set after the script instead of before it, etc.. It's also not true that any arg containing `=` will be treated as a variable setting as awk has rules it applies to identify file names that contain `=`. The ONLY time to set variables in the file list is to change their value between files if you don't have gawk/BEGINFILE or if specific escape handling needed.

Comment: @Edmorton In what way are escapes handled differently?  Can you give an example? I disagree with your final sentence, and would say that the only reason to use -v or a BEGIN block is if you have a specific reason.